# android audio upload to mysql and play audio in website

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uploading an audio recording to mysql and playing in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807239/uploading-an-audio-recording-to-mysql-and-playing-in-website)

Is it possible to do as the title says? upload an audio file thats been recorded in the app to a mysql database and then with php play the file in a webpage

If this is possible can anyone help me with this problem

I have an upload phone app that uploads either images or audio recordings. The image can be uploaded to a mysql database and displayed no problem in a webpage, The problem i am having is playing the audio on the webpage, i have tested the webpage by playing mp3 files i have placed in the database myself though the webpage. When i upload an mp3 file from the phone or emulator nothing plays. The database is populated with a file size and on the webpage a media player does load, but nothing play