# play audio on website with quicktime

Tags: html, quicktime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uploading an audio recording to mysql and playing in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807239/uploading-an-audio-recording-to-mysql-and-playing-in-website)

Hi, I have some code to embed some audio, if i open the page in chrome then i get the quicktime logo with a question mark. If i run the code in firefox then it allows me to download the file then it plays fine. How do i embed the player so the audio just plays instead of downloading?

embed code

```
<object width='391' height='298'> <embed src='apr.amr' width='391' height='298'></embed>'ERROR' </object>
```