# Download a file from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uploading an audio recording to mysql and playing in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807239/uploading-an-audio-recording-to-mysql-and-playing-in-website)

I have .mp3's stored in a MySQL database and i would like to know if there is any php code so a user can visit my website and download the file to play on there computer

Answer

```
  $test2 = @mysql_query("select * from media_link where instance_id = $id");
    $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($test2);

    $media = $result2['media_id'];

header('Content-Type: audio/amr');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.mp3"');
echo $fileContents;
```