# images downloading instead of being displayed

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am storing images on a mySQL server as mediumblobs.  When I try to display them with the following code, some browsers(such as safari and EI) download the image instead of displaying them.  Is there a way to display them which is browser independent?

```
$query = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($image);
$stmt->fetch();
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $image;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932249/show-a-blob-image-php-mysql-along-with-other-data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525830/displaying-an-image-stored-in-a-mysql-blob, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760754/how-to-display-an-image-from-a-mysql-blob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Content-Type: image/jpeg` instead of `Content-Type: image/jpg`

`image/jpeg` is the correct MIME-Type for jpeg images.

Answer (score 3):

Try sending a `Content-Disposition` header with the value `inline` like this.

```
$query = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($image);
$stmt->fetch();
header("Content-Type: text/html");
header("Content-Disposition: inline");
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($image);
$stmt->fetch();
header("Content-Type: text/html");
echo $image;
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($image);
$stmt->fetch();
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo "<p>".$image."</p>";
```

Also note, some browsers do download an image if there is not HTML content. have you tried other browsers?